# Rails routes interpolate optional params in redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have redirect link in my routes as follow.

```
match '(:locale)/products', to: redirect('%{locale}/products/new', status: 301),  via: 'get'
```

Here param `:locale` is optional.

So in case when param `:locale` is empty, I get error message:

```
key{locale} not found
```

A possible workaround would be to use block in redirect instead, where I can add custom logic e.g.

```
match '(:locale)/products', to: redirect{ |params|"#{params[:locale]}/products/new"}, status: 301,  via: 'get'
```

But is there any way to interpolate optional param in the shorter form without using blocks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried with my model User.
It looked like

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  get '(:locale)/users' => redirect( '/users?locale=%{locale}', :status => 301 )
  # get '(:locale)/users' => redirect { | params | "/users?locale=#{params[:locale]}" }, :status => 301, :constraints => { :locale => /[a-z]{2,2}/i }
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

First I didn't get an error when :locale was missing because the "resources" before and second you could set a constraint to ensure the parameter is there.

does this help?

**UPDATE**

```
get '(:locale)/users' => redirect( '/users?locale=%{locale}', :status => 301 ), :defaults => { :locale => "de" }
```

There is also the possibility to set a default value.

Comment: No it does not. If I set the constraint then simply route will not be matched and it would obviously won't produce error. That way I will have to make 2 routes, one for missing locale and other for provided. This way, we would not take advantage of optional parameters at all.

Comment: Right. `:defaults` solves the problem. It can also be set as `{:locale=>""}` if we don't need to set the locale at all. Accepted. Thanks.